# Problem with Cirillic. How can I change code table (cp1251 or koi-8)?

Tags: code

How can I change code table (cp1251 or koi-8)?

I did not find any preference for it.

Comment: The same question & how to set up the default text table? As an alternative solution is install "Geany" text Editor